# multiple queue waiting time

Tags: java, queue, exponential

There are more than 2 queues in the system.

[image]

Packets following the exponential distribution(lamda, mu) continue to enter each queue(queue1, queue2)

However, the service rate mu is processed once for queue1, one for queue2, onece queue1, and once for queue2.

That is, when processing a packet in queue1, the waiting time of queue2 increases. and the waiting time of queue1 increases when processing queue2.

At this time, how do I calculate the waiting time in queue1 and queue2?

I use a java language.

lamda is arrival rate, mu is service rate, how do I get the waiting time through this?

Because of this, I'm leaking a few nights, please help me...

```
    package scheduling;

    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class q_learning_final2 {

private final double alpha = 0.1;
private final double gamma = 0.9;
private static final double rqstate = 0.2;
private static final double rqstate2 = 0.0;
private static final double rqstate3 = -0.2;

private final double rwtime = 0;
private final double rwtime2 = 0;
private final double rwtime3 = 0;
private static double num = 5.0;
private static double num1 = 5.0;
static int cnt=0;
public static class State {
    public double lambda;
    public double ts;
    public double simulationTime;

    public State(double lam, double ts, double simTime) {
        this.lambda = lam;
        this.ts = ts;
        this.simulationTime = simTime;
    }
}

public static class State2 {
    public double lambda;
    public double ts;
    public double simulationTime;

    public State2(double lam, double ts, double simTime) {
        this.lambda = lam;
        this.ts = ts;
        this.simulationTime = simTime;
    }
}

public static class State3 {
    public double lambda;
    public double ts;
    public double simulationTime;

    public State3(double lam, double ts, double simTime) {
        this.lambda = lam;
        this.ts = ts;
        this.simulationTime = simTime;
    }
}

public static class Event {
    public int id;
    public double interarrival;
    public double arrival;
    public double service;
    public double serviceStart;
    public double serviceEnd;
    public double tw;
    public double tq;

    public void function(LinkedList<Event> schedule, State state, double time) {
        Event next = schedule.removeLast();
        if (this.serviceEnd < next.arrival) {
            next.serviceStart = next.arrival;
        }
        if (this.serviceEnd >= next.arrival) {
            next.serviceStart = this.serviceEnd;
        }
        next.serviceEnd = next.serviceStart + next.service;

        if(cnt==0) {
            next.tw = next.serviceStart ;//is this correct?
            System.out.println(next.tw);
            cnt=1;

        }else if(cnt==1) {
            next.tw = next.serviceStart-next.arrival ;//is this correct?

            cnt=0;

        }
        next.tq = next.serviceEnd - next.arrival;           
        schedule.addLast(next);
    }
}

public static class Event2 {
    public int id;
    public double interarrival;
    public double arrival;
    public double service;
    public double serviceStart;
    public double serviceEnd;
    public double tw;
    public double tq;

    public void function(LinkedList<Event2> schedule2, State state2, double time2) {
        Event2 next = schedule2.removeLast();
        if (this.serviceEnd < next.arrival) {
            next.serviceStart = next.arrival;

        }
        if (this.serviceEnd >= next.arrival) {
            next.serviceStart = this.serviceEnd;

        }
        next.serviceEnd = next.serviceStart + next.service;
        if(cnt==0) {
            next.tw = next.serviceStart - next.arrival;//여기 건드려야해
            cnt=1;
        }else if(cnt==1) {
            next.tw = next.serviceStart;//여기 건드려야해
            cnt=0;
        }

        next.tq = next.serviceEnd - next.arrival;

        schedule2.addLast(next);
    }
}


public static double exponential(double lambda) {
    Random R = new Random();
    return -(Math.log(1 - R.nextDouble()) / lambda);
}

public static State initializeState(double lambda, double ts, double simTime) {
    System.out.println("Lambda\tTs\tSimulationTime");
    System.out.println(lambda + "\t" + ts + "\t" + simTime);
    State state = new State(lambda, ts, simTime);
    return state;
}

public static State initializeState2(double lambda, double ts, double simTime) {
    System.out.println("Lambda\tTs\tSimulationTime");
    System.out.println(lambda + "\t" + ts + "\t" + simTime);
    State state2 = new State(lambda, ts, simTime);
    return state2;
}


public static LinkedList<Event> initializeSchedule(State state) {
    LinkedList<Event> schedule = new LinkedList<Event>();
    double time = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5000; i++) {
        Event event = new Event();
        event.id = i;
        event.interarrival = exponential(state.lambda);
        event.service = exponential(state.ts);
        time += event.interarrival;
        event.arrival = time;
        schedule.push(event);

    }
    return schedule;
}

public static LinkedList<Event2> initializeSchedule2(State state2) {
    LinkedList<Event2> schedule2 = new LinkedList<Event2>();
    double time = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        Event2 event2 = new Event2();
        event2.id = i;
        event2.interarrival = exponential(state2.lambda);

        event2.service = exponential(state2.ts);
        time += event2.interarrival;
        event2.arrival = time;
        schedule2.push(event2);

    }
    return schedule2;
}

public static void printResults(double wait, double turnaround, int count, State state, double time) {
    double tw = wait / count;
    double tq = turnaround / count;

    System.out.println("\nResults of Queue 1");
    System.out.println("Number of Events Processed:\t" + count);
    System.out.println("Average Wait Time in Queue 1:\t" + tw);
    System.out.println("Average Time in System 1:\t" + tq);

}

public static void printResults2(double wait2, double turnaround2, int count2, State state2, double time2) {
    double tw2 = wait2 / count2;
    double tq2 = turnaround2 / count2;

    System.out.println("\nResults of Queue 2");
    System.out.println("Number of Events Processed:\t" + count2);
    System.out.println("Average Wait Time in Queue 2:\t" + tw2);
    System.out.println("Average Time in System 2:\t" + tq2);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    State state = initializeState(4.0, 10.0, 100);
    State state2 = initializeState2(3.0, 10.0, 100);

    LinkedList<Event> schedule = initializeSchedule(state);
    LinkedList<Event2> schedule2 = initializeSchedule2(state2);


    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;

    double time = 0.0;
    double time2 = 0.0;
    double time3 = 0.0;

    double wait = 0.0;
    double wait2 = 0.0;
    double wait3 = 0.0;

    double turnaround = 0.0;
    double turnaround2 = 0.0;
    double turnaround3 = 0.0;

    while (time < state.simulationTime) {
        Event event = schedule.removeLast();
        if (time == 0.0) {
            event.serviceStart = event.interarrival;
            event.serviceEnd = event.serviceStart + event.service;
            event.tw = event.serviceStart - event.arrival;
            event.tq = event.serviceEnd - event.arrival;
        }
        event.function(schedule, state, time);
        count++;
        time = event.arrival;
        wait += event.tw;
        turnaround += event.tq;


    }

    while (time2 < state2.simulationTime) {
        Event2 event2 = schedule2.removeLast();
        if (time2 == 0.0) {
            event2.serviceStart = event2.interarrival;
            event2.serviceEnd = event2.serviceStart + event2.service;
            event2.tw = event2.serviceStart - event2.arrival;
            event2.tq = event2.serviceEnd - event2.arrival;
        }
        event2.function(schedule2, state2, time2);
        count2++;
        time2 = event2.arrival;
        wait2 += event2.tw;
        turnaround2 += event2.tq;

    }

    printResults(wait, turnaround, count, state, time);
    printResults2(wait2, turnaround2, count2, state2, time2);

}
```

}

And I wrote it in the source code is this correct?, is this correct?..

Comment: "Is this correct". Does it give you the desired result or not? That's a simple question you should be able to answer yourself. If you can't how shall we when you did the coding?

Comment: i did not write this source code myself, but i brought it and modified it. it seemed to print the right result, but it was a little hard to understand, so i asked.